# Under what conditions are thermodynamic fluctuations a random walk?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, stochastic-processes

Say we have a partition function

$$
\begin{align}
Z=\sum_{i}e^{-\beta E_i}
\end{align}
$$

The fluctuations along the energy $E$ are given by;

$$
\begin{align}
\overline{(\Delta E)^2}= \frac{\delta^2 \ln{Z}}{\delta \beta^2}
\end{align}
$$

Under what conditions will the fluctuations of $E$ causes it to undergo a random walk?

Comment: Statistical mechanics considers the long time averages of quantities in thermodynamic equilibrium. There is no notion in the theory of the dynamics of how a system gets from one microstate to another, as this has already been averaged away. Put another way it is much more natural to ask "when does a random walk obey the predictions of statistical mechanics?" than vise versa.

Comment: @Symmetry Okay, so when does it?